# Ссылки на PSD-макеты с сеткой bootstrap (12 колонок)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Привет.

Хочу потренироваться верстать PSD-макеты с сеткой bootstrap (12 колонок). В интернете нашел только один такой макет. Кто знает, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылки на такие макеты.

Comment: На практике зачастую случается так - дизайнер создавая макет не задумывался о 12 колонках бутстрапа, даже если в макете присутствует шаблон сетки, а заказчик требует верстать на бутстрапе, причем в пиксель перфект. Поэтому советую вам попробовать научиться любой макет верстать под бутстрап. Тогда макет изредка встречающийся на практике, отрисованные под бутсрап будет верстаться на раз два. Удачи.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, если макет создавался без бутстрапа, а потом на него повесили сетку, то при верстке будет немного другой вид, так как некоторые элементы придется сдвигать и менять размеры

Comment: бутсрап это лишь основа, с помощью которой вы верстаете. Это не фиксированный набор правил, который невозможно изменить. Вы в любом случае будете писать свой css. Даже у самого бутстрапа есть свой официальный кастомизатор http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ - создавайте свой config.json и вперед. Если макет создавался без бутстрапа, то на бутсрапе и с помощью его и своих правил сделать пиксель перфект возможно. Т е возможно сделать идентичный вид.

Answer (score 2):

**например, здесь**: https://symu.co/freebies/templates-4/ 
есть макеты различной сложности, выбрать можно по своему уровню. 
правда структура у макетов не всегда хорошая, зато бесплатно:)

Comment: спасибо, нашел несколько